# How to fix glitching grey bar while hovering over cells

Tags: front-end, linux, predictive-interface

I'm using Mathematica 12.1.1.0 on Arch Linux with i3wm and whenever I hover over a cell
or over the suggestion bar a small grey bar appears that is glitching through other cells
(see image)[image: gltiching grey bar torhough out8]

[image]

Is it possible to deactivate this grey bar ? Or is there a better way to fix this issue? I tried searching in the inspector but I did not found the a way to turn it of. Additionally the blinkin cursor is while blinking not completly disappearing. So when the cursor shouldn't be visible I still see a small dot but I could live with that.

Comment: The gray bar is part of the suggestion format, and it seems unlikely that it can be eliminated.  Also, please do not use the `bugs` tag until others verify that a bug actually exists.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, have you tried a different window manager? I wouldn't really expect different behaviour but you never know...

Comment: I don't have a different window manager installed at the moment but I will look into that.

Comment: @CarlLange Ok, I tried a different window manager and I still have the same problem I even figured that if I add more cells the grey bar is getting bigger

Comment: I presume you're using X11, not Wayland? And also, what graphics card and driver combo are you using? (I have no idea what's causing this - really my questions are to help you gather helpful information for a bug report to WRI.)

Comment: Yes I'm using X11 with an Nvidia RTX 2070 and the current proprietary nvidia driver. My distro is Arch with the 5.12.5 Kernel.

Comment: I experience precisely the same problem, Debian, i3wm, Mathematica 12.2.0, NVidia Quadro K4000, NVIDIA proprietary driver 460.73.01, dual screen setup, everything else works flawlessly. With Gnome classic window manager, the grey bars are gone. When trying to click boxes in the Mathematica Preferences window, I have to click next to the box in oder to activate/deactivate.
@KimJongTiramisu: Did you find a solution/workaround still using i3wm? Does anybody else happen to have an idea?

Comment: @jbroedel Yeah it seems to be fixed in the newest version of Mathematica (12.3). Sometimes small minor bugs still appear but that's nothing in comparison to before. You can test the newest version for 15 days for free

Answer (score 1):

I have the Windows version, probably it works the same as yours. In Windows version of MMA: open Edit/Preferences/Interface and uncheck: "Show Suggestion Bar after last output":

[image]

Comment: That kind of reduces the problem but it only seems to be a hotfix. I have still some graphical glitches (for instance the blinking cursor doesn't "blink" correctly) but it's usable now